# What is light and how does it travel?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, aether

My question is: **What is light, and, more specifically, how does it travel?**

I've been contemplating [a theory that I watched on Youtube](http://youtu.be/4Bb627wkjmQ?t=5m53s) *(which has no real credibility to my knowledge)*, the Cosmic Matrix Displacement Model. I was intrigued by one certain aspect, discussed starting at 5:53 (the video is linked to that time), which talks about strings in String Theory being 4 dimensional Vortispheres, which are explained in the video.

Basically, my interest in this is that it brought me to question my acceptance of the idea of light just being waves capable of traveling through **empty** space. I had never thought the phenomenon through any further than that. So the specific piece of my question, "How does light travel?" is inspired by the contemplation of the fact that light (and all energy) must need *some* sort of structure to travel through.

The concept explained in the video is that Vortispheres statically fill the universe and transfer 100% of their motion energy as they rebound off of each other.

[image]

The model asserts that the pre-universe matrix was:

[image]

(according to the model) When motion did occur in the space-time quantum vacuum, Vortispheres formed from the matrix substance with the sheer sphere boundary layer between the still matrix and the moving Vortispheres.

[image]

The Vortispheres continued to form and expand exponentially out through the new universe and were rebounding off of each other, transferring 100% of their motion energy to the next Vortisphere upon impact with zero friction loss.

**According to the model, the minute length of time it takes for a Vortisphere to move across the matrix gap and impact the next Vortisphere establishes the average speed of light at 299,793,458 meters per second.**

**So anyway** the video goes on to explain its explanation of the creation of matter and the workings of gravity, with gravity working in precisely the same way as molecular diffusion. Be that correct or incorrect as it may be, it sparked my curiosity on the subject of how light moves through empty space.

---

**A Programmers's Metaphor**

As a programmer, I'd sum up my question as being similar to me just accepting that JavaScript works, without caring about all the complex layers infrastructure programmed at lower levels to make it seem simple. Waves of light being like simple JavaScript and Vortispheres in the video being like complex Assembly code at a lower level. Hopefully this helps clarify what I'm asking somewhat. I'm curious about the infrastructure that acts as a medium for the light waves to work.

Of course, asking these questions may just be a silly task, since when you explain the "Assembly" infrastructure to me, I'll want to about what makes the Assembly work, and so on and so forth forever and ever in an endless chain of curiosity that will go on as long as we continue to ask questions... bleh. Physics...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is a vacuum able to propagate light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109982/)

Comment: Sorry, but that video is pure and utter *nonsense*. Light is capable of propagating in a vacuum *just fine*.

Comment: @Danu you misunderstand my question. Have a look at my added "Programmer's Metaphor" -- I'm asking *how* it happens.

Comment: @JohnRennie the possible duplicate link does not answer my question. The top answer there is essentially "It just works."

Comment: The point is that your question is predicated on the assumption that there is a problem with light propagating in a vacuuum. The point of the question I linked is that no such problem exists. Light is an excitation in a quantum field, and that quantum field fills all of spacetime so there is nothng mysterious about the fact light can propagate in a vacuum. There is some justification to your complaint that the answer comes down to *it just works*, but at the popular science level that's about all you can say.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yeah, I guess, as I sort of said on my own in the last sentence of my question: With science,  the only answer that will ever truly be correct will take the form of "Here's what we think we know, and here's what we just don't know yet."

Comment: Let's be clear about this, the ultimate arbiter is experiment. If our theories make predictions that are borne out by experiment then we consider our theories to be good. The theory used in this case, [Quantum Electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics), makes [exquisitely accurate predictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_tests_of_QED).

Comment: @JohnRennie but now that I think about it,  have to correct you: You interpret that my queston is predicated on the assumption that there is a problem with light propagating in a vacuum. But that isn't the case. I'm 100% sure that there's no problem at all with light traveling through empty space. My question is a matter of 'How does it happen?"

Comment: And the answer is quantum electrodynamics.

Comment: @JohnRennie and just to comment back on that last thing, yep, I agree with that. We could even potentially solve the physics of our universe to the point that we could put the perfected equation into a giant computer and calculate (predict) exactly what's going to happen at the next given instant in time by feeding the calculation all of the information of the universe's current state. In other words, we can solve physics completely. But there'll always be "So... what created physics?".

Comment: That's a question for http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes, yes it certainly is haha.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean with "how does light travel?". The only answer I can think of is "obeying Newton's law".