# How can light travel in a vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, aether

Lets get on to it!

we know that a wave is simply a disturbance in a certain surface or any kind of a field and this should be common to every wave even light.
The problem comes with the property of light that it can travel without the necessity of any material medium i.e. vacuum.

*So when light is travelling in a vacuum how can it be travelling as a disturbance i.e.wave when there is no substance to create a disturbance?*(Or **How can something i.e. light travel through nothing as a wave?)**

I know for sure that vacuum cannot act as a field for disturbance to happen or take place on it because it is not a "thing" it is just the absence of "anything". Please answer in a understandable manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electromagnetic waves require a medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19670/)

Comment: Or https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156606/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109982/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55109/25301, etc

Comment: maybe this could be removed as a basis for copy question but I like asking questions instead of surfing them on the site that's just my habit and if you don't like it well..don't like it ... you can't do anything about that !

Comment: [James Clerk Maxwell proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) that if the laws of electricity and magnetism that were known in his day were true, then electromagnetic waves _must_ propagate through vacuum at a universally-constant speed. On the surface, his proof _is_ the answer to your question. If you try to investigate on deeper levels though (e.g., To find out why certain supporting laws are true), then you may bump into unanswered questions.  The fact that there _are_ unanswered questions is the main reason why we still have physicists today.

Comment: @MythicalMiner well formed answers may require a good deal of time to construct. It's courteous to search first for similar questions before posting your own, as to reduce the likelihood of unnecessary time being spent on new answers.

Comment: @MythicalMiner I don't necessarily disapprove or dislike duplicate questions, usually they're good because it brings more attention to old questions and maybe new insights. But you really ought to try searching prior to asking, it could save you some time.